# Do Android and iOS device have unique id?

Tags: android, iphone, ios

I need unique id, like device id.

Tell me the length of Android and iOS device(unique) id.

And uuid, device id, android id, make me confused...

What is formal name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a unique Android device ID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id)

Answer (score 5):

Accessing iOS device UDID is deprecated in iOS5 and Apple also rejects apps that uses device UDID.

```
NSString *udid = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
```

Instead you can you [identifierForVendor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006902-CH3-SW49), that is identical between apps from the same developer.

For Android, see answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id).

Comment: I am not iOS Developr. I need length can contain both android & iOS id.

Comment: iOS UDID is 40 characters hex string.They are 40 characters in length, consisting of alphanumeric characters. (a-f0-9). And is always unique for each device.
Where as the Android ID as a 64-bit hex string, that is generated and stored when the device first boots. It is reset when the device is wiped. See this official Android Developers Blog posting: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html